# Why i deploy my project to hosting but it show only homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

Why i deploy my project to hosting but it show only homepage.

it cant go to other page

https://outsource-proj-git-main-petepattapee.vercel.app/ cant go to login page (/login)

https://github.com/petepattapee/outsource-proj this my code

i try to upload to other hosting but it same result

Hoping someone  can help me . Thank you

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't use vite routing and when you click on "Login", a server try get html from /login dir. I suppose the sever havent dir /login. You can use vite routing or reconfig your server for get /index.html when you requested any url

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).